# Como hacer bucle archivo.writelines('\n')

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hola tengo el siguiente codigo que enteoria deberia crear un bucle de lineas vacias y luego poner algo

```
i = 0
i = int(i)
i = i + 1
for _ in range(5):
    archivo = open("archivo.txt",'w')
    archivo.writelines('\n')
archivo.writelines(str(i))
archivo.close()
```

pero esto da una linea vacia y la siguiente con un uno

en vez de cinco lineas vacias y luego un uno.
Sin el for y poniendo cinco veces archivo.writelines('\n') funciona bien pero me parece que queda poco profesional alguien.
Alguien sabe como hacerlo de la otra forma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Explicación

El problema está en esta linea:

```
archivo = open("archivo.txt",'w')
```

Que se ejecuta en cada iteración del for. El modo "w" le dice a Python "abre el archivo y borra todo lo que contiene".
Entonces, cada vez que empieza la nueva iteración del for, el archivo es reabierto y su contenido borrado.

Esto termina teniendo el efecto de la linea vacía y el 1 por que luego del bucle for no vuelves a abrir el archivo en modo "w".

Aquí la pregunta sería: ¿Por qué reabrirías un archivo una y otra vez si puedes abrirlo una sola vez e ir escribiendo (lo cual es más rápido)?

#### Solución

Simplemente abre el archivo fuera del bucle for, antes de cualquier intento de escribirlo:

```
i = 0
# Esta linea está de más. 0 ya es un numero de base 10 y lo estás tratando de convertir a uno de base 10.
# Pero lo dejaré por las dudas.
i = int(i)
i = i + 1

archivo = open("archivo.txt",'w')

for _ in range(5):
    archivo.writelines('\n')
archivo.writelines(str(i))
archivo.close()
```